# Update values in rows based on conditions

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
my_data = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), status_2017 = c("alive", "alive", "alive"), status_2018 = c("alive", "dead", "alive"), status_2019 = c("alive", "dead", "dead"), height_2017 = rnorm(3,3,3), height_2018 = rnorm(3,3,3), 
                     height_2019 = rnorm(3,3,3) , weight_2017  = rnorm(3,3,3), weight_2018 = rnorm(3,3,3), weight_2019 = rnorm(3,3,3))

  id status_2017 status_2018 status_2019 height_2017 height_2018 height_2019 weight_2017 weight_2018 weight_2019
1  1       alive       alive       alive    6.505447    7.328302  4.14945261   2.4715195    7.140026    1.843526
2  2       alive        dead        dead   -2.033761    3.553849  0.09896499   0.4159123    4.340485    1.366350
3  3       alive       alive        dead    3.107110    2.967456  6.52980219   1.6573734    3.397389    3.116294
```

**My Question:** If the ID is "dead" in certain years, I want to replace the corresponding height and weight information in those years to be NA.

I tried to do this using index/subsets:

```
dead_rows <- my_data$status_2018 == "dead" | my_data$status_2019 == "dead"

my_data[dead_rows, c("height_2018", "height_2019", "weight_2018", "weight_2019")] <- NA

  id status_2017 status_2018 status_2019 height_2017 height_2018 height_2019 weight_2017 weight_2018 weight_2019
1  1       alive       alive       alive    6.505447    7.328302    4.149453   2.4715195    7.140026    1.843526
2  2       alive        dead        dead   -2.033761          NA          NA   0.4159123          NA          NA
3  3       alive       alive        dead    3.107110          NA          NA   1.6573734          NA          NA
```

I dont think this is correct - ID = 3 is "alive" in 2018, but their information in 2018 has been replaced with NA:

**Can someone please show me how to fix this? Is there a more "compact" way of doing this that does not require to write the names of all columns?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the years are ordered for status, height and weight, we can get the index of dead, then use that as an index for height weight columns to set to NA.

```
cols <- colnames(my_data)
ix <- my_data[, startsWith(cols, "status")] == "dead"

my_data[, startsWith(cols, "height")][ ix ] <- NA
my_data[, startsWith(cols, "weight")][ ix ] <- NA

my_data
#   id status_2017 status_2018 status_2019 height_2017 height_2018 height_2019 weight_2017 weight_2018 weight_2019
# 1  1       alive       alive       alive   1.0577329    5.212449  -0.4152272    4.001597    1.248253   -1.311515
# 2  2       alive        dead        dead  -0.4002848          NA          NA    8.066520          NA          NA
# 3  3       alive       alive        dead   5.4231554   10.285862          NA    2.619418   -1.995656          NA
```